# while ($stmt->fetch()) not fetching all rows

Tags: php, sql, loops, fetch

I am trying to display all recipes belonging to a logged in user using the while loop. I noticed that let's say, the user have 4 recipes, the first one will not be displayed, resulting in only 3 recipes appearing in the table. If the user have 3 recipes, the first one will not be displayed, resulting in only 2 recipes being displayed and so on.

I had done my research and found out that this is because the first row will be ignored and hence it is not displayed.

Is there anybody who can suggest what kind of corrections should i make to the loop to fix this problem?My codes involves displaying in a table, this is why i am still not able to figure out what should be done despite having looked at other questions which were already posted and answered.

Many thanks!

```
<?php

// 0: Instead of hard coding I shall declare the value first

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

// 1: Connect to forumdb database

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "recipedb") or exit("Error connecting to database");

// 2: Prepare the statement to select recipename,recipeid,,imagefile belonging to the $userid from recipe table

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select recipename,recipeid,imagefile from recipe where userid=?");

// 3: Bind the values

$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);

// 4: Execute the statement

$stmt->execute();

// TODO 5: bind results into $recipename,$recipeid and $imagefile

$stmt->bind_result($recipename, $recipeid, $imagefile);

if ($stmt->fetch() == null) {
    echo "You did not have any recipes yet.<br />";
}
else {
    echo "<table style=width:100% >";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Recipe</b></td><td><b>Actions</b></td></tr>";

    // Use while loop to fetch messages and put in a <table>
    // if

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr>";

        // 6: In 1st <td>, display recipename,recipeid,imagefile

        echo "<td><b>$recipename</b><br /><b>Recipe ID:</b>$recipeid<br /> <img src='images/$imagefile'    height='125' width='125'              >   </td>";

        // 7: In 2nd <td>, display View hyperlink
        // The View hyperlink links to recipedetails.php
        // The delete hyperlink links to deleterecipes.php

        echo "<td> <a href='recipedetails.php?recipeid=$recipeid'>View</a>&nbsp";
        echo "<a href='deleteconfirmation.php?recipeid=$recipeid'>Delete</a>&nbsp";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

// 8: close the statement

$stmt->close();

// 9: close $mysqli

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, when you do this:

```
if($stmt->fetch()==null)
```

the code fetches the first row. If it doesn't exist, the condition triggers. Otherwise, it goes on, and when you start fetching rows "for real", the first one has already been fetched.

What you could do instead is checking the number of rows returned:

```
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "You did not have any recipes yet.<br>";
}
```

Comment: Does that return the correct amount of rows if you don't use `mysqli_stmt::store_result()`?

Comment: @Sumurai8: No it doesn't, see the [documentation of mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Hi, i had replaced                                                                              if($stmt->fetch()==null){
 echo "You did not have any recipes yet.<br>";
 }                            with Joel Hinz's suggested code.However this time the webpage shows a message telling me that the user do not have any recipes when he actually has 4 recipes.

Comment: Thanks guys. Forgot about `store_result()` - you can try adding that, should work, see amended example.

Comment: Hi Joel, thank you so much for your help. The data retrieval is now working fine! Thank you so much!

Comment: They store result function is very useful.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! If it helped you, would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

...even this is a bit old. The problem is that you fetch 2 times if there is a result (one in the comparison and one at the begin of the while loop). Therefor the first record is skiped. Instead of using a "while" loop a "do while" avoids this as the next fetch happens at the end of the loop.